# DJango REST Framework: add additional functionality to ModelViewSet create method

Tags: python, django, rest, overriding, django-rest-viewsets

I am attempting to add to the django server additional functionality upon  different host requests.

To do do so, I overridden the ModelViewSet functions with thought to add functionality within those functions.

What I saw is that when setting a breakpoint on **retrieve** and **list** (GET requests), the debugger stopped. But when trying to break on **create** or **update** (POST requests) the debugger didn't break.

How to resolve this?

One more detail (which is actually the answer to the question), is that I used the *admin* interface to perform the **create** and **update** (unlike the **retrieve** and **list** which I used the REST framework).

```
class GraphViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Graph.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GraphSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ModelViewSet, self).create(request, args, kwargs)
        return response

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ModelViewSet, self).retrieve(request, args, kwargs)
        return response

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ModelViewSet, self).update(request, args, kwargs)
        return response

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ModelViewSet, self).partial_update(request, args, kwargs)
        return response

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ModelViewSet, self).destroy(request, args, kwargs)
        return response

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ModelViewSet, self).list(request, args, kwargs)
        return response

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ModelViewSet, self).post(request, args, kwargs)
        return response
```

Python 3.6.3
Django 1.11.7
djangorestframework 9.0.1

Appreciate also any additional possible solutions for adding functionality on the server side to the different client requests.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the *admin* interface doesn't use the REST framework to access the Django Model.